# How to view execution plans in SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-linux, azure-data-studio

I have SQL Server installed on Linux. It was installed from Microsoft's repos as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu

In MySql I used to write `EXPLAIN` in front of my query to see the execution plan. In SQL Server it doesn't seem to work. But I don't have the studio program installed, only just SQL Server and the `sqlcmd` tool.

How do I see the execution plan of a query in SQL Server on Linux?

Comment: Take a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180765(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This issue has been fixed.Please check

Comment: Thank you! It works

Comment: @Gherman:See updated for one more option which is more easy to work with

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft released a new tool called [SQL Operations studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio),this is similar to SSMS,but is available on Windows,Linux,Macos.

**location for download:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download

Below is a screenshot of how it looks like

[image]

**To view actual execution plan using sqlopsstudio(steps same for all platforms)**

- Press  <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>
- Type run query with actual execution plan  as shown below and select the highlighted, you will get an actual execution plan

[image]

**To view estimated execution plan :**

Just press the ICON shown below

[image]

**You can also use a keybinding to view actual execution plan .Below are the steps**

1.Press  <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>
2.Type keyboard shortcuts
3.In the search plan type actual as shown below
[image]
4.Right click actual query plan shortcut and say `add key binding` with a key of your choice(for me it is <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd>

[image]

**Below Part of the answer was  written during the time when SQLOPS studio is not available.This can ben helpfull for any one who don't have SQLopsstudio:**

Currently viewing execution plan is supported only if you are on Windows,using SSMS or some third party tool like SQLSentry..

There is a feature request being tracked here :[Return ShowPlan data as Text or XML with Query Execution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/509)

one more option is to connect using VSCODE on linux and set `show plan xml` as shown in screenshot below..this provides xml of execution plan

```
SET showplan_xml ON;
```

[image]

you can take that xml and upload it [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) website  and can view plans

Below is a screenshot of above XML

[image]

you can also view it in SQLSENTRY plan explorer as well(Windows only) for more indepth analysis

[image]

Comment: I copied the xml of plan to this site but it says:`The supplied XML is not a valid SQL Server query plan xml.` I have the XML but I can't read it

Comment: I am working with the author of this .I have supplied the repro as well,Author says it should work and he will get back to me..I will have an update once i hear from him

Comment: This is great news

Comment: Any alternative to this to view the explain plan?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET STATISTICS XML ON;
```

try this command in Azure data studio to get actual execution plan.